# Python 3.6.3 - blackjack

Tags: python-3.x, blackjack

I'm programming a blackjack game on python 3.6.3 and I ant to assign this:

```
def total(hand):
    total = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":
            total+= 10
        elif card == "A":
            if total >= 11:
                total+= 1
            else:
                total+= 11
    else:
        total += card
    return total
```

but it says that i have an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide the code in a proper 'code block' for clarity

Comment: `card` must be a tuple, not a string like you expect. Check the data in `hand`.

Comment: Ok, and how do I do that?

Comment: And your algorithm is flawed. A hand of A, 5, 9 will total 25, when it shlould be 15. The correct method is to add 1 for aces, and then only after totalling all the cards, add 10 if the total is < 12 and there's at least one ace.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found out the flaws and I've already corrected it!